# Conditional replacement in vector based on the another character vector in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, conditional-statements, character

I have a dataframe with column that called "mutation". They could be SNP like "C > A", insertion like "+TTTAAG" or deletion like "-CTTGA". For example:

```
**position** **mutation**
1234           C > A
1452           +TTTAAG
2734           -CTTGA
```

I want R to search for specific character in mutation column (">", "+" or "-") and write "SNP", "insertion" or "deletion" respectively into a new column in dataframe, so I would expect following result:

```
**position** **mutation**  **mutation_type**
1234           C > A             SNP
1452           +TTTAAG         insertion
2734           -CTTGA           deletion
```

I tried to do following stuff:

```
mutation_type <- rep(NA, length(df$position)))
df$mutation_type <- mutation_type #creating a new column with NAs
```

trying:

```
while(grep(pattern = "-", df$mutation)){
  df$mutation_type <- "deletion"
}
```

just overwrite every cell in mutation_type column. Could you give me an advice how to solve this issue, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `grep` and `ifelse`:

```
genotype <- data.frame(position = 1:3,
                       mutation = c("C > A", "+TGCA", "-ACGT"))
genotype$mutation_type <- 
    ifelse(grepl("\\+", genotype$mutation), "Insertion", 
           ifelse(grepl("\\-", genotype$mutation), "Deletion", "SNP"))

  position mutation mutation_type
1        1    C > A           SNP
2        2    +TGCA     Insertion
3        3    -ACGT      Deletion
```

Comment: @makkreker you can accept my answer if it helped to solve your problem